# Многопользовательская переносимая БД для C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net

Доброго времени суток. Ни как не могу определиться с базой данных для моего проекта. Гуглить уже сил нет, куча результатов и все не то, возможно неправильно формулирую запрос.

Требования проекта следующие:

- .Net Framework 4.0 (требуется поддержка Windows XP)
- запуск с любого носителя
- БД находится на этом же носителе
- возможность синхронизировать базы данных между несколькими пользователями с разными носителями
- возможность программно создавать/добавлять таблицы в БД, а также столбцы таблиц
- работа с БД без установки дополнительного ПО, то есть подойдут переносимые dll. Или, если уже существует встроенная в .Net Framework возможность работы с БД по перечисленным требованиям, пнуть меня ссылкой

Прошу сильно не пинать, уже больше года не занимался программированием. Теперь понадобилась прога для себя. А прежде чем начать, надо определиться с БД.

**Дополнение**

Немного дополню требования. Например, имеются несколько ПК соединенных по локальной сети. На всех ПК установлен мой проект, в каждом проекте своя БД (этот проект связан с авторемонтом с несколькими боксами/гаражами, назовем этот проект "Программа учета"), но все эти базы данных должны синхронизироваться. То есть приехал начальник в один гараж, вставил флэшку со своей "Программой учета" и синхронизировался с базой данных своих работников, потом поехал в другой гараж и сделал то же самое и т.д. Попав домой, посмотрел отчеты, сделал выводы. Соответственно, база данных на всех ПК во всех гаражах примерно будет одинаковой, а у начальника она будет самой полной, и данные об авто, однажды приехавшего в другой гараж, будут и на других ПК. Проблема вся в отсутствие интернета в гаражах, при наличии интернета многие вопросы бы отпали. А бывает даже, мне приходится с ноутбуком выезжать на ремонт, соответственно интернета на трассе вообще может не оказаться. А бывает какой то ПК/ноутбук выходит из строя из-за специфики работы, потому содержать сервер БД вообще никак... Саму программу я уже сделал больше года назад, но там вся база построена на XML файлах, т.к. работал я один. А теперь расширился... Также было бы предпочтительно, чтобы БД поддерживала многопользовательский режим, чтобы "Программа учета" работала с БД на другом ПК при наличии сети, а у себя в папке держала копию БД, и при отсутствии сети работала со своей БД. При появлении сети происходит синхронизация и далее опять с БД на другом ПК. Как то так...

Comment: я так понимаю, что MySQL будет в виде отдельной dll внутри проекта?
Еще вот натолкнулся на ScimoreDB Embedded Database, что нибудь об этом продукте известно?

Comment: Благодарю, уже скачал mysql-connector-net-6.9.5.msi и устанавливаю. Попробую осилить...

Comment: @krupennikov: Тогда я переведу комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут куча http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database
Я бы остановился на sqlite или firebird в зависимости от потребностей.

**UPD**
Есть несколько вариантов реализации репликаций:

- [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/) поддерживает множество субд.
- [rqlite](https://github.com/otoolep/rqlite) непосредственно для SQLite
- [How to do replication of Firebird databases](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq249/) непосредственно для Firebird (SymmetricDS тоже в списке)
- Можно написать свой репликатор, особенно если изменений не много или они простые, скажем полная копия таблиц или вообще баз.

В общем надо пробовать. На самом деле для любой распределенной базы можно найти инструменты (внешние или встраиваемые), которые решат задачу. Выбирайте и вперед.

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос. Надеюсь, я более подробно описал цель проекта. Теперь вопрос: по этим потребностям подойдет sqlite?

Comment: @krupennikov, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемые господа, 
я для решения этой проблемы предложил бы на узлах сети держать MongoDB, и динамически объединять их в репликасет.
Как мне кажется, такая конфигурация решает такие проблемы: 
1) вы пишете в локальную базу - а все изменения расползаются по всему репликасету.
2) когда один из компьютеров "отваливается" от репликасета - то оставшиеся сами выбирают нового "главного".
Вот совсем краткая инфа про то, как это работает:

http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/11/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mongodb-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0/

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/